# Make Sphinx generate RST class documentation from pydoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydoc

I'm currently migrating all existing (incomplete) documentation to [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

The problem is that the documentation uses [Python docstrings](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/docstrings.html) (the module is written in C, but it probably does not matter) and the class documentation must be converted into a form usable for Sphinx.

There is [sphinx.ext.autodoc](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html), but it automatically puts current docstrings to the document. I want to generate a source file in ([RST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)) based on current docstrings, which I could then edit and improve manually.

How would you transform docstrings into RST for Sphinx?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The autodoc does generate RST only there is no official way to get it out of it. The easiest hack to get it was by changing `sphinx.ext.autodoc.Documenter.add_line` method to emit me the line it gets.

As all I want is one time migration, output to stdout is good enough for me:

```
def add_line(self, line, source, *lineno):
    """Append one line of generated reST to the output."""
    print(self.indent + line)
    self.directive.result.append(self.indent + line, source, *lineno)
```

Now autodoc prints generated RST on stdout while running and you can simply redirect or copy it elsewhere.

Comment: Nice, I just want to add the directory of that file `~/.virtualenvs/docs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/`, if you use virtualenv. File name is, of course, `autodoc.py`

Comment: For newbies like me, remember to use parens in Python 3.x, the new line should be `print(self.indent + line)`

Answer (score 4):

monkey patching autodoc so it works without needing to edit anything:

```
import sphinx.ext.autodoc
rst = []
def add_line(self, line, source, *lineno):
    """Append one line of generated reST to the output."""
    rst.append(line)
    self.directive.result.append(self.indent + line, source, *lineno)
sphinx.ext.autodoc.Documenter.add_line = add_line
try:
    sphinx.main(['sphinx-build', '-b', 'html', '-d', '_build/doctrees', '.', '_build/html'])
except SystemExit:
    with file('doc.rst', 'w') as f:
        for line in rst:
            print >>f, line
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no automated tools to do this.  My approach would therefore be to write a small script that reads relevant modules (based on sphinc.ext.autodoc) and throws doc strings into a file (formatted appropriately).