# Emit reStructuredText from sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

CPython doesn't use autodoc for its documentation - we use hand-written prose.

For PEP 3144 (the ipaddress module), I'd like to use sphinx-apidoc to generate the initial reference documentation. That means I want to run a two-pass operation:

1. Use sphinx-apidoc to emit a Sphinx project for the module that depends on autodoc
2. Run a sphinx builder that creates new reStructuredText source files, with all the autodoc directives replaced by inline reStructuredText content and markup that produces the same output

The first step is straightforward, but I have no idea how to do the second step and can't even think of good ways to search for any existing projects along these lines.

Comment: whats wrong about using rst files generated by autodoc (so only autodirectives no full py-domain definitions) and extend them?

Comment: ipaddress already has extensive docstrings, so I don't want to have to copy and paste them and reformat them by hand for the rest docs.

Comment: So why do you have to copy them? You can write your additional documentation 'between' the auto directives and let sphinx translate it, no need to copy. Sorry perhaps I don't understand you (or your question).

Comment: @ncoghlan:  Any feedback on the two answers provided?  I will award the bounty tomorrow.

Comment: @bmu The CPython docs build process doesn't have autodoc enabled (by deliberate choice)

Comment: @ncoghlan As I don't know the advantages of not to use `sphinx.autodoc` I ask this in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523653/1301710

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had same problem and for one time generating of docs I've used quite ugly solution to patch Sphinx, see [Make Sphinx generate RST class documentation from pydoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668187/make-sphinx-generate-rst-class-documentation-from-pydoc).

Comment: +1 as I think this is the only way to get the rst-source fully formatted by autodoc. There should be an event in autodoc to get it. (also see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer, more or less a starting point:

`autodoc` translates auto directives to python directives.
So one can use autodoc events to get the translated python directives.

For example if you have the following `mymodule.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
This is my module.
"""

def my_test_func(a, b=1):
    """This is my test function"""
    return a + b 

class MyClass(object):
    """This is my class"""

    def __init__(x, y='test'):
        """The init of my class"""
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = y 

    def my_method(self, z): 
        """This is my method.

        :param z: a number
        :type z: float, int
        :returns: the sum of self.x and z
        :rtype: float
        """
        return self.x + z
```

`sphinx-apidoc` will create

```
mymodule Module
===============

.. automodule:: mymodule
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

The following extension (or addition to `conf.py`):

```
NAMES = []
DIRECTIVES = {}

def get_rst(app, what, name, obj, options, signature,
            return_annotation):
    doc_indent = '    '
    directive_indent = ''
    if what in ['method', 'attribute']:
        doc_indent += '    '
        directive_indent += '    '
    directive = '%s.. py:%s:: %s' % (directive_indent, what, name)
    if signature:  # modules, attributes, ... don't have a signature
        directive += signature
    NAMES.append(name)
    rst = directive + '\n\n' + doc_indent + obj.__doc__ + '\n'
    DIRECTIVES[name] = rst 

def write_new_docs(app, exception):
    txt = ['My module documentation']
    txt.append('-----------------------\n')
    for name in NAMES:
        txt.append(DIRECTIVES[name])
    print '\n'.join(txt)
    with open('../doc_new/generated.rst', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join(txt))

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-signature', get_rst)
    app.connect('build-finished', write_new_docs)
```

will give you:

```
My module documentation
-----------------------

.. py:module:: mymodule


This is my module.


.. py:class:: mymodule.MyClass(x, y='test')

    This is my class

    .. py:method:: mymodule.MyClass.my_method(z)

        This is my method.

        :param z: a number
        :type z: float, int
        :returns: the sum of self.x and z
        :rtype: float


.. py:function:: mymodule.my_test_func(a, b=1)

    This is my test function
```

However as `autodoc` emits no event, when the translation is completed, So further processing done by autodoc has to be adapted to the docstrings here.