# Can I override the docstring for a specific class property in Sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

Using Sphinx 2.2.0 and python 3.6.8

I have two classes, `A` and `B`, and a property of `A` generates an instance `B`.  I would like my sphinx html output to reference object `B`, but I would like the raw docstring not to have any sphinx/rest formatting. I am using autodoc and most of the methods and properties in `A` do not require this modification, but I would like to do it in a couple of places if possible.

```py
class A(object):
    """
    This is class A.
    """
    @property
    def getB(self):
        """
        Get an instance of B.
        """
        return B()

    # A also includes many other methods and properties which 
    # I want to document using autodoc

class B(object):
    pass
```

I can write `` Get an instance of :class:`<B>`. `` in the `getB` docstring, but then `A.getB.__doc__` or `help(A.getB)` contain that exact text.  I would like `A.getB.__doc__` to stay `Get an instance of B` but have the reference in the html output generated by autodoc.

```
class A  
Bases: object  

    getB  
        Get an instance of B̲.
```

Assuming A is in a.py, I have tried

```
.. automodule:: a
   :member: A
   :exclude-member: getB

   .. method:: getB
      :property:

      get an instance of :class:`<B>`.
```

However this does not place B within the A class documentation or properly reference class B.

```
property a.getB
Get an instance of B.

class A
Bases: object
```

I have also tried `.. method:: a.getB` and `.. method:: a.A.getB` with no success.

Short of trying to [get the autodoc output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377576/emit-restructuredtext-from-sphinx-autodoc) and modifying it directly, is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to place the output from `.. method:: getB` within the documentation of class `A`, you need to use `autoclass` instead of `automodule`.

```
.. autoclass:: a.A
   :members:
   :exclude-members: getB

   .. method:: getB
      :property:

      Get an instance of :class:`B`.
```